# asp .Net MVC layout shared model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a legacy asp.net application that has a layout view which uses numerous calls to `@Html.RenderAction` to inject fragments of HTML from other controllers / actions.

One of these action methods renders a shared navigation tab bar (dark green) as in the example below (all green shaded objects are in the layout). Another part of the page (also dark green) uses the exact same model as the navigation tab.

[image: Layout with multiple parts of the page that rely on the same model data]

So the problem is that these Action methods make identical back-end calls to render the page. The same model is used in the content area as well, so 3 identical back-end calls are made to render a view when only one should be necessary. The same can be said of all pages in the application.

So in the case of the navigation, I'd like to introduce an abstract base ViewModel and strongly type that to the Layout view. Then I can change the `@Html.RenderAction` to `@Html.RenderPartial` and inject the shared model.

Does that seem like a sensible approach? If the navigation partial view was specified on each view I could pass the data without having to strongly type the layout. Having said that, the data in question **is** common across the whole application so the layout makes sense.

I guess the issue is that I have always thought of the layout as being a container for common application 'chrome' which hasn't required a model to render it (e.g. footers, logos, title etc). Is there any reason why the strongly typing of the layout is wrong / to be avoided?

Comment: you can't strongly type a layout view AFAIK. You could strongly type a partial view which you inject into it. Or you could just write some razor code directly into the Layout view to pull the navigation data you need, and then remove that code from wherever else it's getting called unnecessarily.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! If I strongly type a partial that is referenced in the layout, where do I set the model for the partial view?

Comment: It's one of the parameters to the RenderPartial helper method, I believe.

Comment: Is the issue that the layout shouldn't have a partial view directly inside it? As it stands, I see what you mean, but in the layout I don't have a model to pass into the partial view.

Comment: Well you can call an action method instead (using RenderAction) which returns a PartialView object, that can have a model supplied to it server-side

Comment: @ADyson, Of course you can strongly type a layout (its not uncommon to have a base view model in a layout, and all the views that use that layout have models deriving from the base view model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't know that,thanks. I'm sure someone told me / I read on a random website it couldn't be done, but then maybe I shouldn't believe what I'm told without trying it

Comment: Just to add I just double checked and layout views can be strongly typed as @stephen-Muecke states. The scenario described by Stephen pretty much describes what I am trying to do.